# Addind DISCUS commenting system to your site

Tags: php, comments, blogs

Can we add DISCUSS Commenting System to a custom PHP website? I know how to add it on a wordpress site but i wanna know if i can integrate DISCUS with a website that is custom made in PHP

Comment: Yes you can add it in your website it's very easy use this universal code https://funtoend.disqus.com/admin/universalcode/

Answer (score 0):

Yes [Disqus](https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/) it really easy to install in any website :)
you just have to put this code in you website :

**HTML**

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
    /**
     *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
     *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
     */
    /*
    var disqus_config = function () {
        this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
        this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
    };
    */
    (function() {  // REQUIRED CONFIGURATION VARIABLE: EDIT THE SHORTNAME BELOW
        var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

        s.src = '//EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js';  // IMPORTANT: Replace EXAMPLE with your forum shortname!

        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Comment: I have this code, but please let me know of what changes i have to make in this code to make it work with my website.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://disqus.com/admin/create and register new site, then click "universal code" and add it to your site as in the example.
Also, check [disqus configuration variables](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables)

Comment: I have this code, but please let me know of what changes i have to make in this code to make it work with my website

Comment: this works by default, just paste into your site and change PAGE_URL and PAGE_IDENTIFIER to your own (url need to be absolute, page idenfier have to be unique). BUT if you want additional features check [disqus configuration variables](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables)